# custom redirect to /admin/app/model/?q='search_criteria'

Tags: django, django-admin

Python 3.6
Django 2.2

In django admin.py I have a button that have function of url redirection.
What I need is when I press that button is to redirect to:
/admin/app_label/model_label/search_criteria.

looks like: "ip/app/model/?q='criteria'"

Created buttons code:

```
return format_html(
        '<a class="button" href="{}">Inventory</a>&nbsp;'
        '<a class="button" href="{}">Log Sync</a>',
        reverse('admin:Inventory_specs_change', args=[obj.id]),
        #The problem is here:
        #I need here redirect to "/admin/Inventory/sync/?q=obj.name" 
        redirect('/admin/Inventory/sync/?q=obj.name')
        )
```

I tried a lot, but nothing helps.

So, how can I achieve this redirection to app_model with search_criteria?

Answer (score 0):

In this `'/admin/Inventory/sync/?q=obj.name'` you are writing obj.name inside quotes,You need to provide the value of obj.name there.
Use python format() function here.

Like this:

```
return format_html(
    '<a class="button" href="{}">Inventory</a>&nbsp;'
    '<a class="button" href="{}">Log Sync</a>',
    reverse('admin:Inventory_specs_change', args=[obj.id]),
    redirect('/admin/Inventory/sync/?q={}'.format(obj.name))
    )
```

Comment: This is not the proper way to redirect, I can't redirect in this way at all; I tried with redirect, reverse, and so on need to find a way for rediret.

Comment: What is the error it gives,when you try to redirect?

Comment: evices with ID "<HttpResponseRedirect status_code=302, "text/html; charset=utf-8", url="/admin/Inventory/sync/">" doesn't exist. Perhaps it was deleted?

Comment: url = "/admin/Inventory/sync/" .The Error is saying that this page doesn't exist.

Comment: are you using this '/admin/Inventory/sync/?q={}'.format(obj.name)? cause in your url "/admin/Inventory/sync/" value of obj.name is missing.

Comment: as I said this is not a proper way to redirect, I just need 1 working way, for redirection I need!;

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.

Stolen code from:

https://github.com/gitaarik/django-admin-relation-links/blob/master/README.md

```
            def get_link_field(url):
                return format_html(
                    '<a class="button" href="{}">Inventory</a>&nbsp;'
                    '<a class="button" href="{}">Log Sync</a>',
                    reverse('admin:Inventory_specs_change', args=[INV_VAR.get('id')]),
                    url
                    # '<a href="{}" class="button">{}</a>', url, label
                    )

            def get_url():
                return reverse(
                  '{}:{}_{}_changelist'.format(
                   "admin",
                   "Inventory",
                   "sync"
                   )
                )
            return get_link_field(
                '{}?{}={}'.format(get_url(), "spec", INV_VAR.get('id'))
                )
```